# Auth0 ProtectedRoute component preventing component from changing with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, auth0

I followed the Auth0 React Authentication guide written here:
https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication

And implemented the `ProtectedRoute` component as outlined in the tutorial:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { withAuthenticationRequired } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { Loading } from "../components/index";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component, ...args }) => (
  <Route
    component={withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
      onRedirecting: () => <Loading />,
    })}
    {...args}
  />
);

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

But now I am having an issue with the ProtectedRoute component that doesn't exist if I use withAuthenticationRequired directly in the export statement of the component that I am trying to protect. I have a web app that contains routes like the following:

```
 <Router>
  {isAuthenticated && <Header />}
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/'>
       {isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <LandingPage />}
     </Route>
     <ProtectedRoute path='/home' component={Home}/>
     <ProtectedRoute path='/events' component={Events}/>
     <ProtectedRoute path='/dates' component={Dates}/>
   </Switch>
 </Router>
```

And my Home component contains something like the following:

```
function Home(){
  return <div className="home-page">
    <Sidebar />
    <ProtectedRoute path={"/home/dogs"} component={Dogs}/>
    <ProtectedRoute path={"/home/cats"} component={Cats}/>
    </div>
}
```

export default Home;

The bug also happens when the Home component doesn't use ProtectedRoute like so:

```
function Home(){
  return <div className="home-page">
    <Sidebar />
    <Route path={"/home/dogs"} component={Dogs}/>
    <Route path={"/home/cats"} component={Cats}/>
    </div>
}

export default Home;
```

I can't explain why it happens, but it prevents the state within the Sidebar component from changing the sidebar's appearance and rendered components.

Here is a link to a codesandbox on how the sidebar *should* work (no auth0).
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routing-problem-2efic

When using ProtectedRoute as in the code above, the active class on the navbar links changes, but the rest of the content stays the same.

However, if I instead take the ProtectedRoute off of the Home component, but use withAuthenticationRequired on the export of the Home component, like so:

```
export default withAuthenticationRequired(Home, {
    onRedirecting: () => (<div>Redirecting you to the login page...</div>)
});
```

and

```
<Route path='/home' component={Home}/> //instead of ProtectedRoute
```

Then everything works as it should.

My questions are:

1. Why is the ProtectedRoute component behaving differently from when withAuthenticationRequired is at the export level?
2. Do I need to protect routes that are nested within a protected route?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't get it, you use `withAuthenticationRequired()` directly in your home component ? If you use a ProtectedRoute component with its path and component, you don't need to use it again on this component. You could use the component somewhere else so only the path displaying your component will be protected.

Comment: @VictorJozwicki While I was using a ProtectedRoute component for the home route I didn't use withAuthenticationRequired on the home component. However, this for some reason created the problem where the sidebar wouldn't respond to the state changes so I switched to using withAuthenticationRequired on the home route and no ProtectedRoute.

Comment: Well to answer your second question first, you don't need to protect nested routes when the parent is protected. If the parent doesn't display, the <Route> component won't display therefore it won't render the component.