# Rewriting custom route to use render prop instead of component prop in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, auth0

I have a React app that uses React Router. I have a bug in my code that is due to something in my custom ProtectedRoute component:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component, ...args }) => (
  <Route
    component={withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
      onRedirecting: () => <Loading />,
    })}
    {...args}
  />
);

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

You can read my other post that goes into my problem in detail here: [Auth0 ProtectedRoute component preventing component from changing with state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707829/auth0-protectedroute-component-preventing-component-from-changing-with-state)

But now I am just trying to rewrite this function to use the `render` prop instead of the `component` prop (which I believe is causing the issue). This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({component: ComponentToRender, path, rest}) => {
    return <Route
        {...rest}
        path={path}
        render={(props) => {
            withAuthenticationRequired(() => (<ComponentToRender {...props}/>), {
                onRedirecting: () => <Loading/>
            })
        }
        }
    />
}
```

Does anyone know how to rewrite this to use the `render` prop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the arrow function you passed to `render` isn't returning anything because you're using body brackets and not using `return`. [Read more about arrow functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

You could do it like this:

```js
render={(props) => (
    withAuthenticationRequired(() => (<ComponentToRender {...props}/>), {
        onRedirecting: () => <Loading/>
    })
)}
```

Comment: This way isn't throwing any errors, but it doesn't render any of my components on the page that are inside of a ProtectedRoute